# Longest word using a vector

Tags: c++

I want to display the longest word from a text file. My first idea was to use `vector` and I tried this:

Edit: check gha.st's answer for the solution and explanation.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
vector <const char*> v;
    char str[100];
    v.clear();


    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(str, 100, file) != NULL){
        char *s = (char*)malloc(100);
        strcpy(s, str);
        v.push_back(s);
    } fclose(file);


    char* Max_Word(vector<const char*> &v){
          char MaxWord[100];
        vector<const char *>::iterator it;
        for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){
            if (strlen(*it)>strlen(MaxWord))strcpy(MaxWord, *it);
        }
        return MaxWord;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But something goes wrong, and I get: `Error 1   error C2601: 'Max_Word' : local function definitions are illegal`

Can someone help me understanding this error?

Comment: `malloc`??  Why not just use `std::vector<std::string>`?  In addition, you have memory leaks.

Comment: Please see here for a solution that does not leak memory.  http://ideone.com/86mnLY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example nests `Max_Word` within another function, `_tmain`. The compiler is telling you that nested functions are illegal in C++. Nested functions are functions `f` whose definition is inside the definition of another function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    void f(int x) {
        lounge(x);
    }
}
```

Instead you have to put it at namespace level, or use a lambda function if you want to create closures:

```
void f(int x) {
    lounge(x);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    int x = getx();
    auto g = [=]() { lounge(x); };
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I copied just the part of the code that I considered that would be relevant. I just edited my post with the entire code that of course, include the main function too.

Comment: @crixi No worries, looks like my guess was correct anyway ;)

Comment: Got it now and solved it. I hate when I spend so much time on so stupid stuffs. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move function  Max_Word out of the  _tmain() block

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have mixed C code with some C++ elements which is a bit confusing for what you wish to do (maybe you come from C background). Anyway in order to find the longest word in characters in a text file I whould suggest the following solution:

```
std::ifstream in(file.txt);
std::string dataline;
std::map<int,std::string> items;
while (getline(in,dataline)){
    std::istringstream ss(dataline);
    std::string item;
    while (getline(ss,item,' ')){
        items.insert(std::make_pair(item.size(),item));
    }
}
std::string largestWord = items.rbegin()->second;
```